# Visual Studio 2010 WinForms designer deletes code in unused event handlers

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, event-handling, designer

My VS2010 WinForms designer keeps doing strange thing.

Let's say I have a button and there's a method/handler assigned to the button's Click event. This method contains some code. Now if I want to stop using the method or just to use it somewhere else, I select the button and open its events list, where I unbind the method from the event.

The result is that the method stays but the inner code is gone.

Why? If it's supposed to be some kind of optimization, then I'm not interested.

Comment: I have never seen what you describe, nor am able to reproduce it.  When you say "unbind the method", do you just empty the text from the Event List and save?

Comment: Yes. I don't even have to save the file. It's really weird.

Comment: I see this too, but only on one specific control - a custom control derived from DataGridView. It's obviously a bug in VS.

Comment: Yes, me too and as Igby notes the bug seems to be associated with a DataGridView

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't ever use that control yet.